# Value cannot be null Parameter name: source at System.Linq.Enumerable.Select[TSource,TResult]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am getting this error for below code.

```
var person = await context.Person.Where(x=>x.ID == 1).ToControllerModel().SignleOrDefaultAsync();

return person.ToViewModel();

static  IQueryable<Person> ToControllerModel(this IQueryable<Person> query)
        {
            return query.Select(i => new PersionModel{
                Name = i.Name,
                Addresses = (i.Contact != null && i.Contact.Addresses != null) ? i.Contact.Addresses.ToControllerModel() : null //causing error - works if removed
             });
        }


static  IQueryable<Address> ToControllerModel(this IQueryable<Address> query)
{
    return query.select( i => new AddressModel {
            Street = i.Street,
            No = i.No,
            City = i.City,
            Postcode = i.Postcode
   });
}
```

I have tried different solutions and below seems to be working fine but not sure why. Could anybody explain why this fixes the issue?

```
Addresses = (i.Contact != null && i.Contact.Addresses != null) ? i.Contact.Addresses.Select(x=>x.ToControllerModel())


static  Address ToControllerModel(this Address query)
{
    return  new AddressModel {
            Street = i.Street,
            No = i.No,
            City = i.City,
            Postcode = i.Postcode
   };
}
```

I am using EF Core.

Comment: The line where you state you're getting the error is missing the `:` part of the ternary operator `?:`. In other words, if the condition is false, you do not have a value being set.

Comment: I think, second part is mandatory and if it is related to the missing `:` part then it should have given error at compile time. Though I am not sure how come code is being complied like this. Or am I missing something

Comment: sorry, that is my typo. I have updated quation

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the second part, if `Contact` or `Contact.Addresses` is `null`:

**Your line:**

```
Addresses = (i.Contact != null && i.Contact.Addresses != null) ? i.Contact.Addresses.ToControllerModel()
```

**Correct would be:**

```
Addresses = (i.Contact != null && i.Contact.Addresses != null) ? i.Contact.Addresses.ToControllerModel() : <provide default initalizer>
```